# Is there a way to stop the flashing of buttons with image when clicked in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-button

When creating a button with an image on it you can specify its background color to be the same as the root background color with the `bg='color'` parameter so that if you have an image with transparent background the result seems nice.
However for some reason when you click on the button, there is a white flash that covers the button for as long the click happens.

I have this code:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Button
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()
root.config(bg='black')

image = Image.open('your_image_file').resize((50, 50))
image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

button = Button(root, width=50, height=50, image=image, bg='black')
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

After importing PIL (if not already) and then filling the appropriate path name to your image the code should run without any problems 
Notice that when you click the image a whity flash that covers the button appears?

I want to get rid of that 
I've tried passing the parameters `highlightcolor` `highlightbackground` and `highlightthickness` and playing around with them but nothing really changes whether I for example change `highlightthickness=0` or `highlightbackground='blue'` 
Is there any way to do that properly?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Oh, I just now realised the `activebackground` parameter does the job
Everything okay now I can modify the whity flash color :P

Comment: Why not use a `tkinter.Label`?

Comment: I just wanted to make the white flash same as my background color so `activebackground` solved my problem